# ROM 4kx8 verilog

Tags: verilog

Estoy intentando implementar una memoria ROM de 4kx8 en verilog, hasta el momento todo iba bien, usé $readmemb para leer un .list con los valores iniciales de la ROM, el asunto es que en el list coloqué un salto en las direcciones

```
0000_0001
0000_0010
0000_0011
0000_0100
@ 55
0000_0101
0000_0110
0000_0111
@ 60
0000_1000
0000_1001
@ 100
0000_1010
```

y cuando leo las primeras 4 direcciones me entrega los valores, peor cuando leo la 55, 56,57,60,61,100 no me tira ningún valor me tira XXXX, ya intenté colocar las direcciones como hex, binario y decimal pensando que así los estaba tomando pero no, adjunto mi código y el testbench.

```
module ROMmemory(input [11:0]direccion, output reg [7:0]salida);
    reg [7:0] memoria [0:4096];
    initial begin
        $readmemb("rom2.list",memoria);
    end
    always @ (*) begin
        salida<=memoria[direccion];
    end
endmodule
```

testbench:

```
reg [11:0]direccion;
wire [7:0]valores;
ROMmemory RM(direccion,valores);
initial begin
        $display("\n");
        $display("ROM 4kx8");
        $display("dirección   |    valores");
        $display("-------------------|---");
        $monitor("%b | %b", direccion,valores);
        #180 direccion=1;
        #1 direccion=2;
        #1 direccion=3;
        #1 direccion='d30;
        #1 direccion='d31;
        #1 direccion='d85;
        #1 direccion=85;
        #1 direccion='h55;
        #1 direccion=61;
        #10 $finish;

    end
```

en el testbench empiezo 180 tiempos después ya que tengo otro modulo anteriormente.

Comment: Cuando especificas lo saltos de memoria con `@` la dirección que especificas es en hexadecimal. Si haces `@37`, `@3C`, `@64` en vez de  `@55`, `@60`, `@100` no te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que el signo `@` y la dirección de memoria deben ir juntos, sin espacios entre medio.

Para indicar una nueva dirección de memoria en un archivo de inicialización, Verilog usa el indicador `@dir`, donde `dir` es la dirección de memoria en hexadecimal (sin prefijo):

```
0000_0001
0000_0010
0000_0011
0000_0100
@55 
0000_0101
0000_0110
0000_0111
@60 
0000_1000
0000_1001
@100 
0000_1010
```

En los archivos para inicializar memoria los valores van separados por *whitespaces*.

#### Demo

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
`default_nettype none

module testbench();

reg [11:0]direccion;
wire [7:0]valores;
ROMmemory RM(direccion, valores);
initial begin
        $display("\n");
        $display("ROM 4kx8");
        $display("dirección   |    valores");
        $display("------------|--------------");
        $monitor("%b | %b", direccion,valores);
        #180 direccion=0;
        #1 direccion=1;
        #1 direccion=2;
        #1 direccion=3;
        #1 direccion=4;
        #1 direccion=5;
        #1 direccion=55;
        #1 direccion=60;
        #1 direccion=100;
        #1 direccion='h55;
        #1 direccion='h60;
        #1 direccion='h100;
        #10 $finish;
    end
     
endmodule
```

produce:

```
ROM 4kx8
dirección   |    valores
------------|--------------
xxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx
000000000000 | 00000001
000000000001 | 00000010
000000000010 | 00000011
000000000011 | 00000100
000000000100 | xxxxxxxx
000000000101 | xxxxxxxx
000000110111 | xxxxxxxx
000000111100 | xxxxxxxx
000001100100 | xxxxxxxx
000001010101 | 00000101
000001100000 | 00001000
000100000000 | 00001010
rom_tb.v:27: $finish called at 201000 (1ps)
gtkwave rom_tb.vcd rom_tb.gtkw
```